# Dynamically Compiling SilveLight 4.0 Error Type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeyword' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0

When I dynamically compile SilverLight 4.0 application using Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, I get the following error.

> Line: 118 ErrorCode: BC30002 Error: Type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeyword' is not defined.
>
> Line: 130 ErrorCode: BC30002 Error: Type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeyword' is not defined.
>
> Line: 141 ErrorCode: BC30002 Error: Type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeyword' is not defined.
>
> Line: 234 ErrorCode: BC30002 Error: Type 'System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeyword' is not defined.

I would appreciate any help on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.helpkeywordattribute.helpkeyword.aspx), this Type is not supported in Silverlight. This means that you need to adjust your code to exclude references to this type. We regularly do this using conditional directives (`#if`).